# Dynamically changing urls

Tags: php, .htaccess

How do I go about changing the urls on my server to be like

root/category/product/

Rather than how my site currently is

root/index.php?page=item&id=xx

I understand it is to do with the .htaccess file and url rewrites but I have come up with

```
RewriteRule ^item&id=([0-9]+)$ index.php/product_name=$1
```

Which doesn't seem to make any difference to the urls at all

Any other problem I think I will have is that the url doesn't display the product name in it at all, so that is something that I will want to include too

Comment: What's the correlation between the "category" and "product" in the URI vs. the "page" and "id" in the query string?

Comment: Currently there is no correlation between the category, the only use categories have at the moment is for navigation

Comment: category in url is static?

Comment: No category in url http://domain.com/index.php?page=item&id=xx

Comment: If you want your URLs to look like `/category/product/` then you better rewrite your **index.php** script to take "category" and "product" as query string parameters or have it know how to get an "page" and "id" from it.

Answer (score 1):

I got the idea of your question,but didn't understand the structure you want to follow. Let me give you an example, may be you can get idea from it and solve your problem.

Lets suppose we have a filename and query string as detail.php?item=computer, and we want it to show as "detail/computer".

```
RewriteRule ^detail/(.*) detail.php?item=$1
```

Comment: Beat me to it, nice example

Comment: Thanks for the response, the url structure is `domain.com/index.php?page=item&id=xx` - at the moment I just want to clean it up to `index.php/id=xx` - when the time comes i will look into how to add the product categories and product name into the url. Which way round does the query work, do I define the url I want to change first or what I want to change the url to? I understand ^detail/(.*) means anything with the prefix detail/ and then any characters that proceed it.. Hopefully this makes sense, I'm sure this isn't as confusing as it seems

Comment: RewriteRule ^index/(.*) index.php?id=$1 - 
And make the hyperlink as index/id-x - So when you get the value of id in code, it will be like $_GET['id'], which will return you the whole thing (id-x), you will need to split or explode it by hyphen(-). For example.-  $id = explode("-",$_GET['id']); - 
and you will have the $id[1] as your value(x).